# How to set up local file references in python-jsonschema document?

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I have a set of [jsonschema](https://json-schema.org/) compliant documents. Some documents contain references to other documents (via the `$ref` attribute). I do not wish to host these documents such that they are accessible at an HTTP URI. As such, all references are relative. All documents live in a local folder structure.

How can I make [`python-jsonschema`](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) understand to properly use my local file system to load referenced documents?

---

For instance, if I have a document with filename `defs.json` containing some definitions. And I try to load a different document which references it, like:

```
{
  "allOf": [
    {"$ref":"defs.json#/definitions/basic_event"},
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "action": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["page_load"]
        }
      },
      "required": ["action"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I get an error `RefResolutionError: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/defs.json'>`

It may be important that I'm on a linux box.

---

(I'm writing this as a Q&A because I had a hard time figuring this out and [observed other folks](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/343) [having trouble too](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/98).)

Answer (score 22):

I had the hardest time figuring out how to resolve against a set of schemas that `$ref` each other without going to the network. It turns out the key is to create the `RefResolver` with a `store` that is a `dict` which maps from url to schema.

```py
import json
from jsonschema import RefResolver, Draft7Validator

address="""
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/address",

  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street_address": { "type": "string" },
    "city": { "type": "string" },
    "state": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
"""

customer="""
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/customer",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "first_name": { "type": "string" },
    "last_name": { "type": "string" },
    "shipping_address": { "$ref": "/schemas/address" },
    "billing_address": { "$ref": "/schemas/address" }
  },
  "required": ["first_name", "last_name", "shipping_address", "billing_address"],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
"""

data = """
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "shipping_address": {
    "street_address": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
    "city": "Washington",
    "state": "DC"
  },
  "billing_address": {
    "street_address": "1st Street SE",
    "city": "Washington",
    "state": "DC"
  }
}
"""

address_schema = json.loads(address)
customer_schema = json.loads(customer)
schema_store = {
    address_schema['$id'] : address_schema,
    customer_schema['$id'] : customer_schema,
}

resolver = RefResolver.from_schema(customer_schema, store=schema_store)
validator = Draft7Validator(customer_schema, resolver=resolver)

jsonData = json.loads(data)
validator.validate(jsonData)
```

The above was built with `jsonschema==4.9.1`.

Comment: I initialize the RefResolver like this: `jsonschema.RefResolver(None, referrer=None, store=schema_store)`. And then the store has entries with an "$id" field like: `"https://example.com/path/subpath/filename.json"`. (This doesn't require any network calls--unless you specify a schema not in the store--since the store contains a cache of any reference we need).

Comment: why you used the **#** sign at the end of the `$ref`? `{"$ref": "base.schema.json#"},` instead of putting it as prefix?

Comment: the # sign (which delineates an [URI fragment](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.5)) is superfluous in the above example. In $ref URIs, the fragment refers to a path within a schema, so, in the above sample `{"$ref": "base.schema.json#/properties/prop/type"}` would resolve to `"string"`.

Comment: After learning a bunch about JSONSchemas over the past 2 years, I improved my sample quite a bit...

Answer (score 10):

You must build a custom `jsonschema.RefResolver` for each schema which uses a relative reference and ensure that your resolver knows where on the filesystem the given schema lives.

Such as...

```
import os
import json
from jsonschema import Draft4Validator, RefResolver # We prefer Draft7, but jsonschema 3.0 is still in alpha as of this writing 


abs_path_to_schema = '/path/to/schema-doc-foobar.json'
with open(abs_path_to_schema, 'r') as fp:
  schema = json.load(fp)

resolver = RefResolver(
  # The key part is here where we build a custom RefResolver 
  # and tell it where *this* schema lives in the filesystem
  # Note that `file:` is for unix systems
  schema_path='file:{}'.format(abs_path_to_schema),
  schema=schema
)
Draft4Validator.check_schema(schema) # Unnecessary but a good idea
validator = Draft4Validator(schema, resolver=resolver, format_checker=None)

# Then you can...
data_to_validate = `{...}`
validator.validate(data_to_validate)
```

Comment: Is this because the JSON schema spec says it is a URI. And URI cannot be relative paths? So if we end up with a relative path, we are not writing a proper spec-compliant json schema?

Comment: My tests show that `definitions` is not necessary. One can just compose complete JSON schema documents without needing the `#...` part. I wonder if the `definitions` is just optional or convention.

Comment: jsonschema 3.0.1 with draft 7 as default is out now (per your comment in the example saying you prefer draft 7)

Answer (score 5):

#### EDIT-1

> Fixed a wrong reference (`$ref`) to `base` schema.
> Updated the example to use the one from *the* docs: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html

#### EDIT-2

> As pointed out in the comments, in the following I'm using the following imports:
>
> ```
> from jsonschema import validate, RefResolver 
> from jsonschema.validators import validator_for
> ```

---

This is just another version of @Daniel's answer -- which was the one correct for me. Basically, I decided to define the `$schema` in a base schema. Which then release the other schemas and makes for a clear call when instantiating the *resolver*.

- The fact that `RefResolver.from_schema()` gets (1) *some* schema and also (2) a schema-store was not very clear to me whether the order and which "*some*" schema were relevant here. And so the structure you see below.

I have the following:

`base.schema.json`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#"
}
```

`definitions.schema.json`:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street_address": { "type": "string" },
    "city":           { "type": "string" },
    "state":          { "type": "string" }
  },
  "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
}
```

`address.schema.json`:

```json
{
  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "billing_address": { "$ref": "definitions.schema.json#" },
    "shipping_address": { "$ref": "definitions.schema.json#" }
  }
}
```

I like this setup for two reasons:

1. Is a cleaner call on `RefResolver.from_schema()`:

   ```py
   base = json.loads(open('base.schema.json').read())
   definitions = json.loads(open('definitions.schema.json').read())
   schema = json.loads(open('address.schema.json').read())

   schema_store = {
     base.get('$id','base.schema.json') : base,
     definitions.get('$id','definitions.schema.json') : definitions,
     schema.get('$id','address.schema.json') : schema,
   }

   resolver = RefResolver.from_schema(base, store=schema_store)
   ```
2. Then I profit from the handy tool the library provides give you the *best* `validator_for` your schema (according to your `$schema` key):

   ```py
   Validator = validator_for(base)
   ```
3. And then just put them together to instantiate `validator`:

   ```py
   validator = Validator(schema, resolver=resolver)
   ```

Finally, you `validate` your data:

> ```py
> data = {
>   "shipping_address": {
>     "street_address": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
>     "city": "Washington",
>     "state": "DC"   
>   },
>   "billing_address": {
>     "street_address": "1st Street SE",
>     "city": "Washington",
>     "state": 32
>   }
> }
> ```

- *This one* **will crash** since `"state": 32`:

```py
>>> validator.validate(data)

ValidationError: 32 is not of type 'string'

Failed validating 'type' in schema['properties']['billing_address']['properties']['state']:
    {'type': 'string'}

On instance['billing_address']['state']:
    32
```

> *Change* that to `"DC"`, and **will validate**.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me. Just want to point out the import dependencies for others also trying this out 
```from jsonschema import validate, RefResolver```
```from jsonschema.validators import validator_for```

Comment: Thank you @khuang834. I adjusted/added a note about that.

Comment: How we can validate `Nested properties` with this approach. Say I have a conditional property `"Zipcode"` in `address.schema.json` . And want to validate based on value of `"city"` in  `definitions.schema.json`.

Comment: @curiousguy maybe I didn't understand your question or it is ill posed. Nevertheless, here are my thoughts that hopefully will help you go through your problem: `zipcode` and `city` go hand-in-hand, they are both part of the/an address. AFAIU, you want to _verify_ that a given `zipcode` is part of a `city`. IMHO that this is external to a _schema validation_: roughly, schema validation is about data types/formats. That being said, you _could_ include a "conditional property" for a set of cities and associate zipcodes (`enum`) for each city in another "cities-definitions.schema.json` probably.

Comment: it works for me but why you added **#** at the end of the ref value`{ "$ref": "definitions.schema.json#" }`? instead of `{ "$ref": "#/definitions.schema.json" }`

Answer (score 3):

Following up on the answer @chris-w provided, I wanted to do this same thing with `jsonschema 3.2.0` but his answer didn't quite cover it I hope this answer helps those who are still coming to this question for help but are using a more recent version of the package.

To extend a JSON schema using the library, do the following:

1. Create the base schema:

```
base.schema.json
{
  "$id": "base.schema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "prop": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": ["prop"]
}
```

2. Create the extension schema

```
extend.schema.json
{
  "allOf": [
    {"$ref": "base.schema.json"},
    {
      "properties": {
        "extra": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
      "required": ["extra"]
    }
  ]
}
```

3. Create your JSON file you want to test against the schema

```
data.json
{
  "prop": "This is the property",
  "extra": true
}
```

4. Create your RefResolver and Validator for the base Schema and use it to check the data

```
#Set up schema, resolver, and validator on the base schema
baseSchema = json.loads(baseSchemaJSON) # Create a schema dictionary from the base JSON file
relativeSchema = json.loads(relativeJSON) # Create a schema dictionary from the relative JSON file
resolver = RefResolver.from_schema(baseSchema) # Creates your resolver, uses the "$id" element
validator = Draft7Validator(relativeSchema, resolver=resolver) # Create a validator against the extended schema (but resolving to the base schema!)

# Check validation!
data = json.loads(dataJSON) # Create a dictionary from the data JSON file
validator.validate(data)
```

You may need to make a few adjustments to the above entries, such as not using the Draft7Validator. This should work for single-level references (children extending a base), you will need to be careful with your schemas and how you set up the `RefResolver` and `Validator` objects.

P.S. Here is a snipped that exercises the above. Try modifying the `data` string to remove one of the required attributes:

```
import json

from jsonschema import RefResolver, Draft7Validator

base = """
{
  "$id": "base.schema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "prop": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": ["prop"]
}
"""

extend = """
{
  "allOf": [
    {"$ref": "base.schema.json"},
    {
      "properties": {
        "extra": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
      "required": ["extra"]
    }
  ]
}
"""

data = """
{
"prop": "This is the property string",
"extra": true
}
"""

schema = json.loads(base)
extendedSchema = json.loads(extend)
resolver = RefResolver.from_schema(schema)
validator = Draft7Validator(extendedSchema, resolver=resolver)

jsonData = json.loads(data)
validator.validate(jsonData)
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to preload all schema fragments to RefResolver cache. I created a gist that illustrates this: https://gist.github.com/mrtj/d59812a981da17fbaa67b7de98ac3d4b

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to dynamically generate a `schema_store` from all schemas in a given directory

`base.schema.json`

```
{
  "$id": "base.schema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "prop": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": ["prop"]
}
```

`extend.schema.json`

```
{  
  "$id": "extend.schema.json",
  "allOf": [
    {"$ref": "base.schema.json"},
    {
      "properties": {
        "extra": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
    "required": ["extra"]
    }
  ]
}
```

`instance.json`

```
{
  "prop": "This is the property string",
  "extra": true
}
```

`validator.py`

```
import json

from pathlib import Path

from jsonschema import Draft7Validator, RefResolver
from jsonschema.exceptions import RefResolutionError

schemas = (json.load(open(source)) for source in Path("schema/dir").iterdir())
schema_store = {schema["$id"]: schema for schema in schemas}

schema = json.load(open("schema/dir/extend.schema.json"))
instance = json.load(open("instance/dir/instance.json"))
resolver = RefResolver.from_schema(schema, store=schema_store)
validator = Draft7Validator(schema, resolver=resolver)

try:
    errors = sorted(validator.iter_errors(instance), key=lambda e: e.path)
except RefResolutionError as e:
    print(e)
```