# unknown url type with python jsonschema for referenced path

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I have multiple large `json-schema` files. There are properties which are common for many schema files.

To remove redundancy between the common schema definitions, separated those in separated schema files and using `$ref` to reference to the individual JSON schema.

My directory structure for all schema files are like

```
/
|- schemas
   |- components
      |- page_layout.json
   |- page.json
```

The content of `page.json` is

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "examples": [],
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [],
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "page_layout", "banner_images"
        ]
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "object"
      }
    },
    "allOf": [
      {
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "const": "page_layout"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "data": {
              "$ref": "components/page_layout.json"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and the content of `page_layout.json` file is

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {},
  "type": "object",
  "required": [],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "backgroundColor": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "templateName": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["linear", "square", "circle"]
    }
  }
}
```

Combining both the files, the example JSON data to be validated is

```
[
  {
    "type": "page_layout"
    "data": {
      "backgroundColor": "#ff00ff",
      "templateName": "square"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "banner_images"
    "data": {
      // Content for banner_images
    }
  }
]
```

Content of `data` will change depending on the `type` value.

I'm using [python jsonchema](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema) to validate the JSON data and the code for validating is

```
import json
import jsonschema
import os
from json import JSONDecodeError


class SchemaValidator:
    def __init__(self, category: str):
        self.category = category
        self.data = ''

    def _schema(self):
        schema_file = self.category.replace(' ', '_')
        schema_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'json_schema', 'categories', '{}.json'.format(schema_file))

        try:
            with open(schema_path, 'r') as file:
                return json.loads(file.read())
        except FileNotFoundError:
            raise Exception('Schema definition missing')
        except JSONDecodeError:
            raise Exception('Schema definition invalid')

    def validate(self, data):
        self.data = data
        try:
            status = jsonschema.validate(json.loads(data), self._schema())
        except jsonschema.SchemaError as e:
            raise Exception(e)

        return status
```

But this is giving error for the `$ref` files as

```
unknown url type: 'components/page_layout.json'
```

Comment: By default, JSON Schema has no awareness of physical files or any notation of a file system. In stead, it uses URI resolution rules to determine the correct schema. Once a schema is loaded, the only notion of relative references it has are based on it's base URI, which you set by using $id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up local file references in python-jsonschema document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968770/how-to-set-up-local-file-references-in-python-jsonschema-document)

Comment: You must create your own reference resolve for each schema you wish to reference. You may do so in a loop if you have many.

Answer (score 3):

You must specify the protocol identifier

```
"$ref" : "file://./components/page_layout.json"
```

https://github.com/python-jsonschema/jsonschema/issues/313